# Reading a header from a .docx (Word) file in Python docx

Tags: python, openxml, python-docx

I'm parsing docx files using the library [python-docx](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx). I need to read the header of documents as well as paragraphs however I can't find anything about document headers in their documentation. There is documentation on writing a header to a new file but none on reading a header. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
I used instead of the "python-docx" package a newer version called python-docx2txt
(https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt) which extract the text with the headers in one line.